# Why document.activeElement displaying previous focused element

Tags: javascript

I have added an `keydown` event listener to get currently focused `DOM Element` but unfortunately when focusing through tab, I am getting previously focused/active element (the element before the currently focused element *if it makes sense*) in `console.log()`

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'Tab':
      console.log(document.activeElement)

      break
  }
})
```

```html
<button> Button </button>
<a href="#"> Anchor </a>
```

Any Idea why this happening?? Try pressing `Tab` after clicking inside the snippet `iframe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keydown` is triggered on the previous element. Suppose you are on `body` and try to get focus to the button next, the activeElement for `keydown` will be body right.

You can use `keyup` to solve this:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  switch (event.key) {
    case 'Tab':
      console.log(document.activeElement)

      break
  }
})
```

```html
<button> Button </button>
<a href="#"> Anchor </a>
```

Comment: Thanks!!  I totally forget about `keydown/keyup`.